# Attempted to dual boot linux with windows, not letting me boot into either

Tags: linux, boot, windows, kali-linux, grub

I was installing KALI on my computer alongside windows. My computer has 3 hard drives. One of them is a 1 TB hard drive running Windows 7. My two are 250 GBs and were both empty. I tried to install KALI Linux 2.0 onto one of the 250 GB hard drives. I configured the GRUB to install onto the second 250 GB hard drive. However, now when I try to boot up my computer, I cannot access either.

This is what I usually do in order to boot :

1. Start computer
2. Press F9 for boot menu
3. Select Hard Drives
4. Select the OS I want (usually Windows 7)

This is what happens now:

1. Start computer
2. Press F9 for boot menu
3. Select Hard Drives
4. I am greeted with a blank black screen, not a list of hard drives like how I usually see. The only thing I can do is shut the system down.

I have tried to reinstall Windows 7 onto the same hard drive, but it is not letting me. It simply says, "No partition found on hard drive". I also tried to reinstall KALI with the same process, but I got the exact same result.

My main priority at this stage is getting Windows back, but getting KALI back would also be a nice bonus. I have a Windows repair disk as well, but when I booted into it, it didn't allow me to restore anything. If you need anymore information, please let me know.

---

UPDATE: I was able to install a copy of windows 7. What do I do with kali now in order to install that.

Comment: Try the suggested fix here http://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=10104.15